# Send email using a different from address then credential id?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a project. User A can send email to the system, then another user B can reply to the email. But I do not want to show the user B's email in the reply. Instead, I'm using a system account (sys@mysite.com) for the SMTP to send the reply. So, the processing is like this:

```
UserA@mysite.com ---> sys@mysite.com
UserB login, check sys@mysite.com, write reply, and send reply using credential of sys@mysite.com
```

I want to show the from email in the reply to be userB@mysite.com instead of sys@mysite.com .

Is this possible by using SMTP? or, it totally depends on the email server, i.e. can be configured? or, can not be done?

I'm using .Net C#.

Thanks

Add more details:

For example, UserB (userB@mysite.com) replies the email with credential of sys@mysite.com (since we can set the credential), userA gets the reply. When open it, the email shows as the email is sent by sys@mysite.com instead of userB@mysite.com . I want to show the from Email as UserB@mysite.com . Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the framework provides apis for all of this.

SmtpClient can be provided a credentials object, which it will use to authenticate.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

MailMessage encapsulates the message data, including from and reply-to.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I added more details in original question. If I use sys@ to send the email, it always shows the email was from sys@ although we can change reply-to or send-from displayname, but the sys@ is always visible on recipient side, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I'm just guessing there, maybe server side behavior? you should be able to verify your code is sending the right headers by watching the wire.

Comment: I'm sending it using .net smtpclient, set the fromAddress (myfrom@) and replyTo (myReply@). Weird is: the reply is still using the smtp account that set in the credential.